# Multivariable chain rule problem with gradient norm.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've been trying to solve this question for my homework for so long no but I end up with nothing. I calculated partial derivatives and tried to solve for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ in order to replace them into de gradient norm, but I seems to go nowhere. The question is the following:

The change of variables $x=u+v$, $y=uv^2$ transforms $f(x,y)$ to $g(u,v)$. If $\|\nabla f(x,y)\|=4$ for every $x$ and $y$. Determine the constants $a$ and $b$ such that:

$a(\frac{\partial g}{\partial u})^2-b(\frac{\partial g}{\partial v})^2=u^2+v^2$

I wolud appreciate any advice.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your formulas for $\partial g/\partial u$ and $\partial g/\partial v$? It does look unlikely that it can work out, however. I suspect an error in the problem.

Comment: $\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}v^2$


,
$\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}2uv$

Comment: Agreed. Even with $uv$ instead of $uv^2$ it isn't close to working out. Pester your teacher.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Should I delete this post then?

Comment: If you end up with a resolution, I'd be curious to know. :)